# How does the "tabs.onUpdated" for Firefox Addons work?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am playing around with the Firefox Addons, so it's mostly new to me. In addition, I don't have much JS knowledge. So on the Docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated) I found the 'tabs.onUpdated" Event and it would fit my need's perfectly (I need a event that runs a function if a tab with a specific url changes url). So I copied the examples and read me through the page but I couldn't get it working. Can somebody help me?
 
Thanks Akira



Code: 

manifest.json:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Testing Add-on",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "Test Add-on",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://developer.mozilla.org/*"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

content_script.js: (just to test if script works)

```
console.log("Before");
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changed) => {
    if (changed.url) {
        console.log("True");
    }
})
console.log("After");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for adding your manifest.json.
In the browser console (the one you open with Ctrl+Shift+J or with `web-ext run --bc`) you can see the following error message:

`TypeError: browser.tabs is undefined`

This is because you are using `browser.tabs` in your content script, whereas you should use it in your background script.

Add the following to your manifest file:

```
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background_script.js"]
    }
```

-> where the background_script.js has the content your content_script.js has.
Leave your content script empty for now. This is the script that will be injected into pages that match given URL pattern.

You could write something like the following into your content_script.js (just for testing):
`document.body.style.border = '5px solid red';`

`True` (from the `onUpdated` handler in your background script) will be printed to the browser console (not the developer tools console!) whenever the URL of that tab changes.
Pages that match your URL pattern will show a red border;)

Comment: Thanks! It worked :) I didn't knew about the browser console. I think I now understand it and can go futher on.

Answer (score 0):

```
    browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changed) => {
        if (changed.url) {
            // URL of tab has changed
        }
    })
```

So, in order for you to tell if a tab with your specific URL has changed its URL you'd have to store a reference to the corresponding tab.

**UPDATE:** You can pass a second parameter `extraParameters` to `addListener`:
`browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(callback, { urls: [/*array of match patters. Fire the event only for tabs whose current url property matches any one of the patterns*/] })`

[match patterns docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say with this update. If "After" is not being outputted then there is something wrong with your code inbetween. Do you see an error message in the console? Have you set the correct permissions in your manifest.json? I copy-pasted your code into my project and it works perfectly fine. Console outputs: "Before", "After", ...tab url changes..., "Url Changed"

Comment: No I don't see any errors. What are the correct permissions? I unfortunately can't look up what mine are because I don't have my laptop with me.

Comment: Permission is called "tabs". Just tested it without this permission. The code won't fail without, but you will not be able to register the `onUpdated` listener. In fact the code is syntactically fine and you should see "Before", "After" printed to the console. I assume you are using this code in your background script?

Comment: It seems like your problem is not the correct usage of `browser.tabs.onUpdated` (as mentioned above: the code works fine), but your extension structure(?) It would help if you'd post all your code somewhere, because otherwise I can't do much more than guessing (sth might be wrong with your manifest keys or background script or ...)

Comment: I currently don't have access to my laptop for 2 days from now, but I will check it all as soon as I can.